# Is there a full list of uwsgi's mythical magic variables?

Tags: uwsgi

I'm trying to do some quite complicated configuration with uwsgi. I'm trying to make things easier on myself in the long run and naturally, in doing so, *I'm making things as hard as could possibly be right now*.

Anyway, I'm looking for the complete list of magic variables. The ones I've been able to find on the [Emperor page](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Emperor) are *not* what I'm after. The page (and others) suggests there's a larger dictionary of magic out there. Somewhere.

```
%v = the vassals dir
%o = the original config filename as specified in the command line
%p = the absolute path of the config filename
%s = the filename of the config file
%d = the absolute path of the directory containing the config file
%e = the extension of the config file
%n = the filename without extension
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The uwsgi docs seem to have been updated since the time this question was asked.  Here is a link to a longer list of magic variables:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#magicvars

Answer (score 4):

the only missing variable is %c that reports he name of the directory containing the config file:

/foo/bar/test/one.ini will return 'test'

Comment: And that's exactly the one I needed! Thanks.